How to find retpoline return thunk for my machine
I'm interested in finding out, how jump2ret works as a mitigation for retbleed. For that I would like to copy the return thunk to a kernel module such that I can play around with it (i.e. write the assembly code that recreates the return thunk in the kernel module). However, I cannot figure out how the assembly code for that looks.
AMD proposed this mitigation (chapter 6.1): https://www.amd.com/system/files/documents/technical-guidance-for-mitigating-branch-type-confusion.pdf
And I believe this is what the Linux kernel implements.
The info I think is in:
linux-hwe-5.15-5.15.0/arch/x86/lib/retpoline.S
linux-hwe-5.15-5.15.0/arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h
But I can't decipher the code.
Does anybody have a starting point that might help me? Maybe the virtual address where this thunk gets placed?
